# Install npm global from a local directory with dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, package

There's a public tool (csso-cli) that can be installed with `npm install -g csso-cli` to be available globally. Now I need to make a modification to it and change one of its dependencies (csso) to a newer version to use the latest features. So I cloned the repository and installed that with `npm install -g ./`. It did copy that local code directory to my global npm installation location, but none of the required dependencies were added. There simply isn't a node_modules subdirectory in the install location.

How can I properly install an npm package from a local directory, including all external dependencies, as if it were installed from a public repository? Maybe I need to create some sort of package file first and install that? I don't know much about npm. I searched the web but couldn't find anything. (All instructions are missing the dependencies.) I've read the npm documentation but am still no wiser. That topic isn't covered here, still only incomplete installations without dependencies seem possible. Who needs that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I needed the `npm pack` command. It creates an archive of the package from the local directory. When installing that file with `npm install -g my-package-1.0.0.tgz` all dependencies are properly installed as well. Plus, the package file doesn't contain the git files.